# What are the basic checks needed to resolve this error - type or namespace name could not be found

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-errors

What are the basic checks I need to do to resolve this error?

Comment: Right click, resolve -> include reference, ??, profit.

Comment: `can you show the code in question here.. so that we can see if you are using a method correctly or not.. this could be quite a few things in your current state based on your question..

Comment: @ChrisHalcrow While self-answers *are* encouraged, the question and answer must still be up to SO quality standards. This one has a ways to go. I would *at least* include the standard form of the error within the question itself. You may also want to make the whole thing community wiki if you are trying to make a canonical duplicate.

Comment: Thanks Bradley - is there a way I can move this question to the community wiki or should I delete this and recreate it on the wiki (assuming its an original topicc). My aim is to get a conversation going that devs can use as a checklist :)

Answer (score -1):

You can look at this first:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w7xf6dxs.aspx

If you're using Visual Studio 2013 you can also right-click the error message and select 'Show Error Help' to view the above page.

A common issue is that if a class isn't being recognised, the class file isn't 'included' in the project (right-click it and select 'Include in Project').

Comment: if you meant this as a Q&A type post....why did you just post a link? At least post some useful content *on this site*

Comment: It's the line 'A common issue is that if a class isn't being recognised, the class file isn't 'included' in the project (right-click it and select 'Include in Project')' that I want to share.

Comment: You need to emphasise that. It *looks* an awful lot like a link-only answer. See my comment on your question for more. BTW, much more common is that someone just misspelled the class/type name :)